# Is it possible for an old version of the application to remain on the hard drive after reinstalling from DEB?

Tags: software-installation, deb

I have `pandoc` installed from DEB (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.16.0.2) on Linux Mint 17.2 because the repository versions are outdated. I just downloaded and installed a new version. `whereis pandoc` only finds one executable on my system, and the date on the `pandoc` file is from only a week ago. Apt also seems to think it is updated to the newest version. However, `pandoc --version` still reports the old version.

```
$ apt-cache policy pandoc

pandoc:
  Installed: 1.16.0.2-1
  Candidate: 1.16.0.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.16.0.2-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.12.2.1-1build2 0
        500 http://mirrors.liquidweb.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

But:

```
$ pandoc --version

pandoc 1.15.0.6
```

**Original Question:** Is it possible for application to stay in memory after being updated to a new version?

After an answer was proposed, it became more clear what the question should have been, so I completely changed the question, although the details are the same.

Comment: Not sure about appropriate tags. Please edit or suggest new ones.

Comment: What does `type pandoc` say?

Comment: @cjm OK, that points to what is going on. The result is `pandoc is hashed (/home/lee/.cabal/bin/pandoc)`, which means that I previously installed pandoc using haskell environment, *not* DEB.

Comment: That makes the question almost completely misguided. Should I alter to actually make this useful, or just kill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible, and a feature**

Your path may be setup so that your running an older version. This is common if one package is in /usr/bin and the other in /usr/local/bin or /opt/something Try running `which pandoc` to make sure your running the same one in that is in the deb file.

This allows for different users to run different versions of applications based on their needs. For example /usr/bin/app and $HOME/bin/app may be completely different versions, but a user may want to run an older version because of an edge case regression, while "everyone else" want's to use new features in the newer version.

Comment: `which pandoc` yields `/home/lee/.cabal/bin/pandoc`, so it is in fact a path issue, with another version installed.

Comment: I just edited the question. Opening line of answer is now inconsistent with the question, but the remainder is useful, and I have selected as correct answer.